# php exec not working in wamp server

Tags: php, cmd, wamp, exec

I'm using wamp server 2.5. and i want when user click on the button, cmd windows opens and search an ip address.

i think i must enable or disable some option in php.ini or apache to get true result.

when i using exec() and etc, page just loading or looping... and no result

like:

```
exec('start cmd.exe @cmd /k "ping www.google.com"');
```

i search a lot and test many script but it didn't works. my friend test it in xampp and it's work.

is any problem in wamp server ?

Comment: Can you post your php.ini?

Comment: windows services generally can't open windows, since they're not allowed to interact with the console...

Comment: At Control Panel / Administrative tools / Services, search for wampapache64, httpd, or something like that. On the Log On tab tick the 'allow service to interact with desktop'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wamp runs as a service, and services cannot show UI applications like the command prompt.

You can can configure the service to interact with the desktop by opening the 'Services' configuration, look for `wampapache64`, open its properties, and on the `Log On` tab check the checkbox `Allow service to interact with desktop`.

But still, PHP runs on a webserver (in this case your PC), so even if it could start a UI application, it would show on the desktop of your PC, not of the client visiting it.

So, back to the drawing board. I wonder if opening CMD is the most important feature. It sound to me like you could also get the IP of a domain in another way. A little search leads me to the function `gethostbyname`.

```
string gethostbyname ( string $hostname )
```

It returns the IP (v4) address of a given hostname, so your script could look like this:

```
<?php echo gethostbyname('http://www.google.com');
```

By the way, `start` starts a new command. `cmd.exe` starts a new command. `cmd` starts a new command. That command starts `ping`. Why not just `exec('ping www.google.com')`?

Comment: thanks alot, its work, but a alert windows opens and request confirmation to view the cmd windows, and after click , windows change to other windows, like changing full screen cmd with windows